# Jquery closing in click

Tags: javascript, jquery

im having a problem in a script that i download it in the web, basically what i need is a FAQ question whit the collapse panel interaction, but in this case different in the other out there i want when i click in one question it opens, and when i click in another question the question before closes and open the one i clicked.

I found this [Collapse panel script](http://feloliveira.com.br/blog/faq-de-perguntas-e-respostas-com-jquery/)

It works well, but is missing one detail, if i click in the same link (question), the question doesn´t collapse back to normal normal mode, its only possible to close him chosing another link. I want to be able to close the question when i chose another question and when i click the same question again.

the javascript code in the main page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!–
  $(function() {
    var $h2;
    var $answer;
    $(‘.answer’).hide();
    $(‘#faq h2′).bind(
        ‘click’,
        function()
        {
            if ($h2 && $h2[0] != this) {
                $answer.slideUp();
                $h2.removeClass(‘open’);
            }
            $h2 = $(this);
            $answer = $h2.next();
            $answer.slideDown();
            $h2.addClass(‘open’);
        }
    )
 });
 –>
</script>
```

Hope for some help

Comment: Could you please try to rewrite this part (ideally with less pronouns): "It works well, but is missing one detail, that is me do be able if i click again in the same link (question), the question closes, to me be able not just close him when i choose another, but also when i click again in the question him closes."

Comment: I edited the question again to better understanding, im sorry for my english.

Comment: Remove the `<!– ->`, this is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: Also change `‘open’` to `'open'` some blog system replace quotes with proper ones (in terms of typography).

Answer (score 0):

First off, I redid the variable names of your script, refactored it slightly, and added comments to try and make it clearer what's going on:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() { // onReady
    var $lastClickedH2;
    var $currentOpenAnswer;
    $('.answer').hide(); // All answers start hidden
    $(‘#faq h2′).click(function() // When an H2 is clicked
        {
            if ($lastClickedH2 && $lastClickedH2[0] != this) {
                // If there was an answer already open, close it
                $currentOpenAnswer.slideUp();
                $lastClickedH2.removeClass(‘open’);
            }
            // Set the last clicked H2/current open answer variables
            $lastClickedH2 = $(this);
            $currentOpenAnswer = $lastClickedH2.next();
            // Show the answer
            $currentOpenAnswer.slideDown();
            // Add an "open" class to the H2 (not sure why ...)
            $lastClickedH2.addClass(‘open’);
        }
    );
 });
</script>
```

As you can (hopefully now) see, when you click an H2 you've already clicked, it does get closed (by the part of your code that's in the `if`), but then the code after that just re-opens it.  What you want to do is tweak things so that it doesn't re-open; here's one way to do it:

```
            ...
            if ($lastClickedH2 && $lastClickedH2[0] != this) {
                // If there was an answer already open, close it
                $currentOpenAnswer.slideUp();
                $lastClickedH2.removeClass(‘open’);
            }
            if ($lastClickedH2[0] == this) { // If we clicked on the same H2 twice
                // Unset the last clicked H2/current open answer variables
                $lastClickedH2 = undefined;
                $currentOpenAnswer = undefined;
                // Stop here
                // (Don't go on to the rest of the code, which would re-open it)
                return;
            }
            // Set the last clicked H2/current open answer variables
            $lastClickedH2 = $(this);
            ...
```

That code should work, but it is untested (so don't be surprised if it has a bug); hopefully it helps.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific as to what's not working for me to be able to help you.